# How to add the chart to specific cell with VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, charts, macros

I wanna to position the chart created with VBA to specific cell position. Here is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Chart'!$A$1:$L$2")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ser As Series
Set cht = ActiveChart
Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
ser.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
ser.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects(1).Chart
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = Sheets("Chart").Range("B4")
End With
Dim Srs As Series
Set Srs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
Srs.Name = "Desired Name"
Dim ChartObj As Object
For Each ChartObj In Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects
ChartObj.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, "Factsheet"
Next ChartObj
End Sub
```

ANy ideas how i could solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ChartObjects.Add(Left, Top, Width, Height)` method. It allows you to specify the chart location in points.

For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim cht As ChartObject
   Dim ser As Series
   Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(20, 20, 400, 150)
   With cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Worksheets("Chart").Range("B4")
    .SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Chart").Range("$A$1:$L$2")
   End With
   Set ser = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
   With ser.Format
    .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
  End With
End Sub
```

See below for more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/ff197613.aspx

Comment: what are that 20,20.150 ? how i could implement this with my code?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example that clearly demonstrates the ChartObjects.Add(Left, Top, Width, Height) method.